# Splay tree implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, binary-search

I am looking into splay trees and I implemented a version. It seems correct. Could someone please let me know if this indeed correct and how to improve it?
I will just show the `insert` item and `splay`. It should be enough.

The code is not that big as it seems in the first look. Briefly, I try to implement the splay tree according to algorithm storing the nodes in the access path in a stack (`thePath`) as I go up.

```
private Deque<BinaryNode<AnyType>> thePath = new LinkedList<BinaryNode<AnyType>>();  
public enum ZIGZAGTYPE{  
        ZIG_ZAG_LEFT,ZIG_ZAG_RIGHT,
        ZIG_LEFT,ZIG_RIGHT,
        ZIG_ZIG_LEFT,ZIG_ZIG_RIGHT  
}  
public enum CHILDTYPE{LEFT, RIGHT};  

public void insert(AnyType x) {  
        thePath.clear();  
        BinaryNode<AnyType> theRoot = root;  
        if(theRoot == null){  
            theRoot = new BinaryNode<AnyType>(x);  
            root = theRoot;  
            return;  
        }  
        while(theRoot != null){    
            int cmp = x.compareTo(theRoot.value);  
            if(cmp < 0){  
                thePath.push(theRoot);  
                theRoot = theRoot.leftChild;  
            }  
            else{  
                thePath.push(theRoot);  
                theRoot = theRoot.rightChild;  
            }  
        }  
        BinaryNode<AnyType> newNode = new BinaryNode<AnyType>(x);  
        if(thePath.peek().value.compareTo(x) < 0){  
            thePath.peek().rightChild = newNode;  
        }  
        else {  
            thePath.peek().leftChild = newNode;  
        }  
        thePath.push(newNode);  
        splay();  
}

private void splay(){  
        if(thePath.isEmpty()){  
            throw new IllegalStateException();  
        }  
        CHILDTYPE childType;  
        BinaryNode<AnyType> parent;  
        BinaryNode<AnyType> grandParent;  
        BinaryNode<AnyType> current;  
        while(thePath.size() > 1){  
            current = thePath.pop();            
            parent = thePath.pop();  
            ZIGZAGTYPE type ;  
            if(thePath.isEmpty()){  
                //we are at root--> ZIG  
                type = type(null, parent, parent);  
                if(type == ZIG_LEFT){  
                    parent = Rotations.rotateWithLeftChild(parent);                 
                }  
                else{  
                    parent = Rotations.rotateWithRightChild(parent);  
                }  
                thePath.push(parent);   
                root = parent;  
            }  
            else{  
                grandParent = thePath.pop();  
                if(!thePath.isEmpty() && grandParent == thePath.peek().leftChild){  
                    childType = CHILDTYPE.LEFT;    
                }  
                else{      
                    childType = CHILDTYPE.RIGHT;  
                }  
                type = type(grandParent, parent, current);  
                if(type == ZIG_ZAG_LEFT){  
                     //ZIG ZAG
                     grandParent = Rotations.zigzagLeft(grandParent);  

                }  
                else if(type == ZIG_ZAG_RIGHT){  
                     //ZIG ZAG
                     grandParent = Rotations.zigzagRight(grandParent);  

                }               
                else if(type == ZIG_ZIG_RIGHT){  
                     //ZIG ZAG  
                     grandParent = Rotations.zigzigRight(grandParent);       
                }  
                else if(type == ZIG_ZIG_LEFT){  
                     //ZIG ZAG  
                     grandParent = Rotations.zigzigLeft(grandParent);  

                }  
                if(!thePath.isEmpty()){  
                     if(childType == CHILDTYPE.LEFT){  
                         thePath.peek().leftChild = grandParent;  
                     }  
                     else{  
                         thePath.peek().rightChild = grandParent;  
                     }  
                     thePath.push(grandParent);  



                }  
                root = grandParent;      

            }  

        }     
    }    

private ZIGZAGTYPE type(BinaryNode<AnyType> grandParent, BinaryNode<AnyType> parent, BinaryNode<AnyType> x){  
        if(grandParent == null){  
            return parent.leftChild == x?ZIG_LEFT:ZIG_RIGHT;  
        }  
        else if((grandParent.leftChild == parent && parent.rightChild == x)){  
            return ZIG_ZAG_LEFT;  
        }  
        else if((grandParent.rightChild == parent && parent.leftChild == x)){  
            return ZIG_ZAG_RIGHT;  
        }
        else{  
            if((grandParent.leftChild == parent && parent.leftChild == x)){  
                return ZIG_ZIG_LEFT;  
            }  
            else{  
                return ZIG_ZIG_RIGHT;  
            }  
        }  
    }  

    private static class Rotations <AnyType>{  
        public final static<AnyType>  BinaryNode<AnyType> rotateWithLeftChild(BinaryNode<AnyType> r){  
            BinaryNode<AnyType> lc = r.leftChild;  
            r.leftChild = lc.rightChild;  
            lc.rightChild = r;  
            return lc;  
        }  
        public final static<AnyType>  BinaryNode<AnyType> rotateWithRightChild(BinaryNode<AnyType> r){  
            BinaryNode<AnyType> rc = r.rightChild;  
            r.rightChild = rc.leftChild;  
            rc.leftChild = r;  
            return rc;  
        }       


        public final static<AnyType> BinaryNode<AnyType> zigzagLeft(BinaryNode<AnyType> g){  
            BinaryNode<AnyType> p = g.leftChild;  
            g.leftChild = rotateWithRightChild(p);  
            g = rotateWithLeftChild(g);  
            return g;  
        }  

        public final static<AnyType> BinaryNode<AnyType> zigzagRight(BinaryNode<AnyType> g){  
            BinaryNode<AnyType> p = g.rightChild;  
            g.rightChild = rotateWithLeftChild(p);  
            g = rotateWithRightChild(g);  
            return g;  
        }  

        public final static<AnyType> BinaryNode<AnyType> zigzigLeft(BinaryNode<AnyType> g){         
            g = rotateWithLeftChild(g);  
            g = rotateWithLeftChild(g);  
            return g;           
        }  

        public final static<AnyType> BinaryNode<AnyType> zigzigRight(BinaryNode<AnyType> g){            
            g = rotateWithRightChild(g);  
            g = rotateWithRightChild(g);  
            return g;             
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not check if the tree is indeed correct, but some comments in your design.

- `rotateWithLeftChild` and `rotateWithRightChild` should be collapsed into some thing like

  ```
  public final static<AnyType>  BinaryNode<AnyType> rotateWithChild(BinaryNode<AnyType> r, Direction d){  
    BinaryNode<AnyType> c;
    switch(d) {
    case Left:
      c = r.leftChild;  
      r.leftChild = c.rightChild;  
      c.rightChild = r;  
      return c;  
    case Right:
      c = r.rightChild;  
      r.rightChild = c.leftChild;  
      c.leftChild = r;  
      return c;
    }  
  }
  ```
- `zigzagLeft`, `zigzagRight`, `zigzagRight`, `zigzagLeft` all should be collapsed into one method that takes an option value, and should do the zig/zag based on it.

  ```
  public final static<AnyType> BinaryNode<AnyType> zigzag(BinaryNode<AnyType> g, ZIGZAGTYPE zz){  
    swtich(zz) {
    case ZigzagLeft:
      g.leftChild = rotateWithChild(g.leftChild, Right);  
      return rotateWithChild(g,Left);  
    case ZigzagRight:
      g.rightChild = rotateWithChild(g.rightChild, Left);  
      return rotateWithChild(g,Right);  
    case ZigzigLeft:
      g = rotateWithChild(g,Left);  
      return rotateWithChild(g,Left);  
    case ZigzigRight:
      g = rotateWithChild(g,Right);  
      return rotateWithChild(g,Right);  
  }
  ```

The advantage is that, rather than

```
             if(type == ZIG_ZAG_LEFT){  
                 //ZIG ZAG
                 grandParent = Rotations.zigzagLeft(grandParent);  

             }  
             else if(type == ZIG_ZAG_RIGHT){  
                 //ZIG ZAG
                 grandParent = Rotations.zigzagRight(grandParent);  

             }              
             else if(type == ZIG_ZIG_RIGHT){  
                 //ZIG ZAG  
                 grandParent = Rotations.zigzigRight(grandParent);  

             }  
             else if(type == ZIG_ZIG_LEFT){  
                 //ZIG ZAG  
                 grandParent = Rotations.zigzigLeft(grandParent);  

             }
```

You can just call

```
             grandParent = Rotations.(grandParent, type);
```

For the function insert

```
public void insert(AnyType x) {  
        thePath.clear();
```

Avoid temptation to use redundant variables.

```
        if(root == null){  
            root = new BinaryNode<AnyType>(x);
            return;
        }
        BinaryNode<AnyType> theRoot = root;
```

Pull out statements that are common in if and else clause
Ternaries help to simplify the if conditions when the variation is in a single place.

```
        while(theRoot != null) {
            thePath.push(theRoot);
            theRoot = x.compareTo(theRoot.value) < 0 ? theRoot.leftChild
                                                     : theRoot.rightChild;
        }
```

I recommend that rather than using two members `leftChild` and `rightChild`, add a 2 element member array child, and refer to each as `child[Left]` and `child[Right]`. The advantage is that your code can be considerably simplified.

Answer (score 0):

I took a slightly different approach to reviewing this code.  I set out to write the missing code and creating a working implementation.  Without access to your BinaryNode class I took [this one](http://users.cis.fiu.edu/~weiss/dsj3/code/BinaryNode.java) and worked to clean up my `SplayTree<AnyType>` class that included your code.  Here are some changes I made and some notes about how they might help you.

I switched over from public fields like `value`, `leftChild` and `rightChild` to `getElement()`, `setLeft()` etc.  There are a lot of arguments for and against.  [Here is one](http://schneide.wordpress.com/2010/10/25/statement-against-public-fields-in-java/) that influenced me, make up your own mind.

You are using a generic type (`AnyType`), but you are calling `compareTo()`.  You will need to make sure you add `extends Comparable<AnyType>>` to your SplayTree class and related methods (I'm assuming you know this because it wouldn't compile, so this note is more for others who follow you).

Finally, You can reduce your zigzig and zagzag function in a small way (it's debatable if it's more readable, but it is some tiny amount more efficient, and to me it looks cleaner)

```
public final static <AnyType extends Comparable<AnyType>> BinaryNode<AnyType> zigzigLeft(BinaryNode<AnyType> g) {
  return rotateWithLeftChild(rotateWithLeftChild(g));
}
```

I like rahul's idea that you can simplify the left/right methods by storing the child nodes in an array and passing a `LEFT` or `RIGHT` index.

I'm going to have fun implementing a `find()` method and checking out if this code is correct.